# jQuery .click() not triggering on links dynamically created with .wrapInner()

Tags: jquery, dynamic, triggers, hyperlink

I'm having an issue with this script and for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong with it. Quick run through what I have:

**The HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li id="wildcard_1">
        <div>
            <a href="#">test</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="reset">reset</a>
```

**The jQuery:**

```
// Main function
$("[id^=wildcard_]").children('div').children('a').click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});

// Temporary reset function
$("a.reset").click(function() {
    $("[id^=wildcard_]").children('div').wrapInner('<a href="#"></a>');
});
```

The "test" link works as it's supposed to the first time is is being clicked -- it is being transformed into plain text). In order not to paste the bulk of the script here, I have created a temporary function that will wrap the contents of the `div`, transforming the "test" plain text back into a link. And this is where it goes haywire -- the `.click()` listener of the first function will not trigger on this dynamically created link anymore and FireBug isn't throwing any errors nor warnings.

You can also see this live on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rWz69/

Any help on this would be more than appreciated !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler, like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^=wildcard_] > div > a" , function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

[Here's your fiddle example updated/working with the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/rWz69/1/) :)

Comment: Asked 1 minute ago, answered 23 seconds ago. I'm pretty sure you're a cyborg, Nick.

Comment: Simply brilliant, and damn fast too ! Funny thing is, the first thought that crossed my mind after seeing your answer was "God, my selector is ugly" :) Anyways, if it's not too much to ask, since my approach almost drove me insane, could you please explain in just a few words why exactly it didn't work so I can avoid it in the future ? Many thanks, buddy !

Comment: @FreekOne - Sure! a `.click()` attaches a click handler to the elements the selector finds *at the time*, that's the important bit, **to the elements**.  If new elements are added...well tough luck they don't get a handler.  `.live()` instead attaches an event listener on `document` that listens for the `click` to bubble up, so it works on current and future elements just the same  :)